# Method function isn't executed when accessed from another class

Tags: java, methods, reference, invoke

I'm studying Java, and have written the following code:

```
public class Funcionario {
    String nome;
    String cpf;
    String rg;
    String dataEntrada;
    String dept;
    double salario;
    double ganhoAnual;
    int mesesEmpresa;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario();
        f1.nome = "Sandra";
        f1.salario = 1500;
        f1.mesesEmpresa = 36;
        f1.recebeAumento(150);
        f1.cpf = "428.768.841-10";
        f1.rg = "49.757.501-6";
        f1.dataEntrada = "12 dez 2006";
        f1.mostra();
    }

    void nome() {
        System.out.println("Funcionario(a): " + nome);
    }

    void data() {
        System.out.println("Data de Entrada: " + dataEntrada);
    }

    void recebeAumento(double aumento) {
        salario = salario + aumento;
    }

    double calculaGanhoAnual() {
        ganhoAnual = salario * 12;
        return ganhoAnual;
    }

    void rgEcpf() {
        System.out.println("CPF: " + cpf);
        System.out.println("RG: " + rg);
    }

    void tempoEmpresa() {

        if (mesesEmpresa % 12 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Tempo de casa: " + mesesEmpresa / 12 + " ano(s)");
        } else {
            int mesesTempo = mesesEmpresa % 12;
            int anosTempo = Math.round(mesesEmpresa / 12);
            System.out.println("Tempo de casa: " + anosTempo + " ano(s) e " + mesesTempo + " mes(es)");
        }
    }

    void mostra() {
        this.nome();
        System.out.println("Salario atual: " + this.salario);
        System.out.println("Ganho anual: " + this.calculaGanhoAnual());
        this.rgEcpf();
        this.tempoEmpresa();
        this.data();
    }
}

class Empresa {

    // is this an array? then why doesn't it have the type, like int[] or long[]?
    Funcionario[] empregados;
    String cnpj;
    String nomeEmpresa;
    private int contador = 0;

    public int getContador() {

        return this.contador;
    }

    // what happens in between the parentheses?
    void adiciona(Funcionario f) {

        if (contador <= 10) {
            this.empregados[contador] = f;
            this.contador++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Array cheio!");
        }
    }

    void mostraEmpregados() {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.empregados.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Funcionario na posicao: " + i);
        }
    }
}

class TestaEmpresa {

    // why does the reference to Empresa and Funcionario array have to be inside main? Otherwise, it gives <identifier> expected error
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();

        // what is happening in the next line, exactly?
        empresa.empregados = new Funcionario[10];

        double salarioModificado = empresa.getContador() * 1500;

        Funcionario f2 = new Funcionario();
        f2.salario = salarioModificado;
        empresa.adiciona(f2);

        Funcionario f3 = new Funcionario();
        f3.salario = salarioModificado * 2;
        empresa.adiciona(f3);

        empresa.mostraEmpregados();
    }
}
```

However, when I invoke `empresa.mostraEmpregados();` in the `TestaEmpresa` class, `void mostraEmpregados() {}` from the `Empresa` class won't run. Therefore, the output is only:

```
Funcionario(a): Sandra
Salario atual: 1650.0
Ganho anual: 19800.0
CPF: 428.768.841-10
RG: 49.757.501-6
Tempo de casa: 3 ano(s)
Data de Entrada: 12 dez 2006
```

I know that we need references for classes, in order to use attributes or methods from them, but I can't get this to work. Could you guys please help me?

P.S.: please, ignore the questions in `//commentary`. I'm working on them by myself.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run? Looks perfectly fine to me. Have you debugged it to really be sure?

Comment: When I run your code, specifically the main method in `TestaEmpresa`, I get 10 lines of output looking like `Funcionario na posicao: 0`, `Funcionario na posicao: 1`, etc.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov: I use an online Java compiler (http://browxy.com/), and the output is just as I mentioned. No, I haven't debugged it.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're running the correct `main()`?

Comment: The Problem is you have **two main methods**. You can only run one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, he can run one main from inside another, it just isn't automagic.

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS: thanks! I didn't know that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main methods: there is one on your class `Funcionario`. Running this one produces the output that you are getting:

> Funcionario(a): Sandra
>  Salario atual: 1650.0
>  Ganho anual:
>   19800.0
>  CPF: 428.768.841-10
>  RG: 49.757.501-6
>  Tempo de casa: 3 ano(s)
>  Data de Entrada: 12 dez 2006

There is another in your class `TestaEmpresa`. Running this one produces this output:

> Funcionario na posicao: 0
>  Funcionario na posicao: 1
>   Funcionario na posicao: 2
>  Funcionario na posicao: 3
>   Funcionario na posicao: 4
>  Funcionario na posicao: 5
>   Funcionario na posicao: 6
>  Funcionario na posicao: 7
>   Funcionario na posicao: 8
>  Funcionario na posicao: 9

So check your running configuration. It looks that you are running the main method on `Funcionario` instead of the one on `TestaEmpresa`.

Comment: Is there a way I could run both at the same time?

Comment: Yes. You can add `Funcionario.main(args);` in `TestaEmpresa.main` or add `TestaEmpresa.main(args);` in `Funcionario.main`. It would depend on your use case. But don't do both things at the same time or you would get an infinite loop of those methods calling each other endlessly.